# Storing a object with localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, phaser-framework

I can't seem to find a way for localStorage to record the clicks variable when I refresh the browser.

I've tried using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, but then found out about parseInt, which seems a better alternative (I'm just trying to store a number).

I'm brand new to programming and all the examples I checked were pure javascript, too complicated/poorly explained or outdated. Hope you can help me out. I've been trying to solve this issue for over a week.

Some more info: I'm using Phaser 2.5.0 with MAMP. Google Chrome v49.0.2623.112 (64-bit), OS X 10.8.5.

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

var scoreText;
var clicks = 0;



function preload() {

    game.load.image('clickBox', 'assets/ClickMe.png');
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#182d3b';
    game.stage.disableVisibilityChange = true; 
}


function create() {

    localStorage.setItem('clicks', parseInt('clicks'));
    localStorage.getItem('clicks');



    button = game.add.button(game.width/2, game.height/2, 'clickBox', upScoreText);


    scoreText = game.add.text(30, 30, "CLICKS: " + clicks, {font: "20px Arial", fill: "#ffffff", align: "left"});

    button.scale.x = 0.5;
    button.scale.y = 0.5;
    button.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    button.inputEnabled = true;
}


function update () {

            scoreText.setText("CLICKS: " + clicks);        
}


function upScoreText () {

     clicks++;
}
```

Comment: So you want to continue with the same number of clicks when the user reloads the page. How will the clicks variable be set to zero? Is there a way for the user to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store the literal `clicks`, but the variable with that name. Also there is no sense in calling `parseInt` on `clicks`, since it already is a number. Moreover, localStorage stores everything as a string, so whatever you do, it will end up being stored as a string anyway.

Storing:

```
localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks); // is always stored as string
```

Reading:

```
clicks = +localStorage.getItem('clicks'); // `+` makes it a number
```

Now you have to put the above statements at the right place. It makes no sense to first write the value to storage and then read it out again: obviously the value will be the same after as before, and no advantage was taken from whatever was stored *before* you did this. You might as well skip those two lines then...

Instead you will want to read the value once, in the `create` function, and write the value whenever you change the it, i.e. in `upScoreText`:

```
function create() {
    // Load. If not exists in localStorage, use 0. 
    // If it does, cast to number with `+`:
    clicks = +localStorage.getItem('clicks') || 0;
    // etc...
}

function upScoreText () {
    clicks++;
    // Save:
    localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks);
}
```

Now you'll have an ever incrementing clicks variable that survives a page reload, but you'll probably need to add a way to reset the value back to 0.

Comment: Thanks trincot, that worked.  Other people who tried to help stated I needed to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse with localStorage.  Later, someone else recommended the use of parseInt. I suppose I can remove the global variable clicks = 0; now.  From all the examples I studied, not one had the +localStorage method.

Comment: Indeed you can remove the `var clicks = 0`. `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` are useful when you want to store/load an object (or array) in/from localStorage, but if your variable converts nicely to string (like is the case with numbers), it is not needed.

Comment: I see... Just one more quick question: my next challenge is to learn how to store multiple variables - what would be the best way to store those values? With an array? Thanks again for the quick help.

Comment: Either store with separate names each of them in localStorage, or use an object with properties, each property having the value you need. In that case, do use `JSON` functions to store and retrieve.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it did suit your needs :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your using parseInt wrong i.e instead of

```
localStorage.setItem('clicks', parseInt('clicks'));
```

You should use

```
localStorage.setItem('clicks', parseInt(clicks));/*removed the quotes for the clicks*/
```

And i think ypu should check first whether the clicks variable exists in localStorage and then assign the variable clicks,but this is just a suggestion.you can implement it like this:-

```
var clicks=localStorage.getItem("clicks")||0;
```

not sure if you wanted this though :/